# I have a issue with xml

Tags: xml, blogger

I wrote a code like this:

```
<b:widget id='header' type='HeaderTitle'/>
```

but after i saved it,

blogger says this:

> The new widget with id "header" has an invalid type: HeaderTitle

Anyone help?

Comment: blogspot? masa' sih @Goblog Banget

Comment: what's the different before and after editing? lolz

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. This simple solution brilliant works for me:

Change

```
<b:widget id='header' type='HeaderTitle'/>
```

to

```
<b:widget id='HeaderTitle1' type='HeaderTitle'/>
```

Name **must** be same as type and with any number (1, 2, 3 etc.).

Answer (score 1):

Blogspot right? okay. this is your previous codes:

```
<b:widget id='header' type='HeaderTitle'/>
```

when you create new widget, you should take notice of two things:

1. widget must be inside of section.
2. each of widgets must contains of type.

HeaderTitle is, indeed invalid type when you modify it. This must be return to the default type, that is: HTML.

**It is better** (the easy method) if you just add new line `section` instead of new line `widget`.
When you're done, you will be able to create new widget (Header) or modify it as you wish with the section.

Just add new line with like this follows:

```
<b:section class='leftsbar' id='leftsbar' showaddelement='yes'></b:section>
```

Here's the **[simple blog tutorial](http://true-blogger.blogspot.com/2015/01/framework-format-of-blogspot-template.html)** with it.